# What do you do in SQL Server to CREATE OR ALTER?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The year is 2009 and SQL Server does not have CREATE OR ALTER/REPLACE.  This is what I do instead.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES 
           WHERE ROUTINE_NAME = 'SynchronizeRemoteCatalog' 
             AND ROUTINE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' 
             AND ROUTINE_TYPE = 'PROCEDURE')
 EXEC ('DROP PROCEDURE dbo.SynchronizeRemoteCatalog')

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.SynchronizeRemoteCatalog
AS BEGIN
    -- body
END
```

For triggers, you have to lean on the proprietary system views.

Is this the most accepted convention in the meantime?

**EDIT:** As n8wrl suggested, the [official word](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=127219) suggests that this feature is not a high priority.  Hence the question.

Comment: Looks like, a short seven-plus years later, SQL Server now [has `CREATE OR ALTER`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3190548/update-introduces-create-or-alter-transact-sql-statement-in-sql-server-2016). Woohoo.

Comment: @ruffin, yep, that's what I do now.  The approaches here are still the best option for earlier versions (which have a long half-life).

Comment: Yay for CREATE OR ALTER, but that's SQL Server 2016 only.

Answer (score 114):

This article makes a good point about losing permissions when dropping an object in SQL server.

- [Tips ‘N’ Tricks – T-SQL – An Elegant way to CREATE or ALTER Stored Procedures in One-Go for Easy Maintenance](https://dattatreysindol.wordpress.com/2015/10/12/tips-n-tricks-t-sql-an-elegant-way-to-create-or-alter-user-defined-views-in-one-go-in-sql-server-for-easy-maintenance/)

So here is the approach which retains permissions:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('spCallSomething') IS NULL
    EXEC('CREATE PROCEDURE spCallSomething AS SET NOCOUNT ON;')
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE spCallSomething ... 
--instead of DROP/CREATE
```

Also works for functions, just replace `PROCEDURE` with `FUNCTION` in the above code.

Another reason to consider doing it this way is tolerance to failure. Suppose your DROP succeeds, but your CREATE fails - you end with a broken DB. Using ALTER approach, you will end up with an older version of the object.

Comment: Yep, that's exactly how I've been doing it for a while now (except the `AS SET NOCOUNT ON`, that's an interesting twist).  Come to think of it, I should set up a yasnippet for this pattern because I type it so much.

Comment: I have written templates to deal with the creating of missing stored procedures, scalar functions and table functions, with good success.

Comment: However, the syntax is incorrect if you "just replace PROCEDURE with FUNCTION".  I have posted [our examples below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36657634/3677773).

Comment: Why is "SET NOCOUNT ON" a good choice for the temporary placeholder sproc body? Asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40849374/is-set-nocount-on-a-good-choice-for-a-placeholder-stored-procedure-body

Comment: I think there is also another excellent reason for using this approach is to avoid mistake concerning potential privileges already setup, e.g. a person other than the DBA has made a change, using drop/create you might end up removing granted privilege you were not aware of.

Answer (score 70):

> The year is 2009 and SQL Server does not have CREATE OR ALTER/REPLACE.

The year is 2016 and it does now have DIE ([Drop If Exists](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SQL-Server/DROP-IF-EXISTS-new-thing-in-SQL-Server-2016/ba-p/384562)) in SQL Server 2016 RTM and `CREATE OR ALTER` (introduced in 2016 SP1).

Taking `Drop If Exists` first the caveats around needing to re-apply permissions with this approach still apply. Example syntax is

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS dbo.SynchronizeRemoteCatalog

GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.SynchronizeRemoteCatalog
AS
  BEGIN
      BODY:
  END 

GO

/*TODO: Reapply permissions*/
```

`CREATE OR ALTER` retains the permissions. Example syntax is

```
 CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.SynchronizeRemoteCatalog
 AS
 BEGIN
   BODY:
 END
```

The [corresponding MSSQL Tiger Team blog post](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SQL-Server/Developers-Choice-CREATE-OR-ALTER/ba-p/384960) explains

> CREATE OR ALTER can be used in programmability objects such as:
>
> - STORED PROCEDURES (including natively compiled)
> - FUNCTIONS (Transact-SQL, including natively compiled)
> - TRIGGERS
> - VIEWS
>
> But cannot be used in:
>
> - Objects that require storage (tables, indexes and indexed views)
> - CLR user-defined functions
> - Deprecated programmability objects (RULE and DEFAULT)
> - Non-programmability objects (such as CREATE ASSEMBLY, CREATE TABLE or CREATE  - SCHEMA). On these objects, the syntax for CREATE and
>   ALTER is very different from a syntax and usability perspective.

Answer (score 6):

We encountered a situation where we needed to update a remote site, but we didn’t have DROP permissions. Until now, we have been using the ‘DROP and CREATE’ script built into SSMS 2008 R2, but now we needed to change.
We created three templates, which we drop above the appropriate ALTER scripts when we need to update a stored procedure or function:

```
—- Stored Procedure
IF OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[<Name_Of_Routine, , >]') IS NULL
EXEC('CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[<Name_Of_Routine, , >] AS SET NOCOUNT ON;')
EXEC('GRANT EXECUTE ON [<Name_Of_Routine, , >] TO Public AS dbo;')
GO

—- Scalar Function
IF OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[<Name_Of_Routine, , >]') IS NULL
EXEC('CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[<Name_Of_Routine, , >] (@i INT) RETURNS INT AS BEGIN RETURN 0 END;')
EXEC('GRANT EXECUTE ON [<Name_Of_Routine, , >] TO Public AS dbo;')
GO

—- Table-based Function
IF OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[<Name_Of_Routine, , >]') IS NULL
EXEC('CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[<Name_Of_Routine, , >] (@i INT) RETURNS @O TABLE(i INT) AS BEGIN INSERT INTO @O SELECT 0 RETURN END;')
GO
```

Any special permissions get scripted after each CREATE (Table functions cannot be assigned permissions). After that, the ALTER doesn’t change it, and if they add or modify the permissions, they remain. Doing it this way, it’s an easy task to copy the name of the function or stored procedure, and use the Template Parameter replacement to automating the completion of these scriptlets.

Now, I’m hoping that the good folks at Microsoft will either add this to their “Script ___ as” lists, or give us the ability to create our own such that this scripting comes ‘baked-in’

You may want to throw some weight behind the SQL Server feedback entry at:
https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/344991/create-or-alter-statement.  It seems to be one of the few that are still accessible publicly, and they state that they "have started a feasibility review for this to decide if we can ship this in the near future."  The more voices, the more likely this will happen!

(Update: now also using the following code for Triggers and Views)

```
-- Triggers
IF OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[<Name_Of_Trigger, , >]') IS NULL -- Check if Trigger Exists
    EXEC('CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[<Name_Of_Trigger, , >] ON [<Name_Of_Table, , >] AFTER UPDATE AS SET NOCOUNT ON;') -- Create dummy/empty SP
GO

-- Views
IF OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[<Name_Of_View, , >]') IS NULL -- Check if View Exists
    EXEC('CREATE VIEW [dbo].[<Name_Of_View, , >] AS SELECT 1;') -- Create dummy/empty View
GO
```

Answer (score 5):

Every time a developer writes `IF EXISTS(...) DROP` a seal pup is clubbed. You should know exactly what's in the database and your upgrade script should do the CREATE or ALTER as appropriate, based on the current version of your application schema: [Version Control and your Database](http://rusanu.com/2009/05/15/version-control-and-your-database/).

Comment: why? Better be safe than sorry! Have you never had a script fail on you and suddenly a sproc you were about to drop is still lingering around in the database? I'd always do a IF EXISTS() check first - just to be on the safe side! Have you never had a silly temp-DBA run some of your scripts several times instead of just once??

Comment: I find this to be a reasonable approach to allowing my deployment scripts to be run many times safely. Besides, if I can club a seal without getting cold...

Comment: @marc_s: this is less of risk if you have strong controls and rely on ALTER (like we do). Any script I give to the DBAs is either safe to run multiple times or it's atomic so it errors out second time.

Comment: I guess I don't live in the ideal world.  What do I say if a script raises an error on a client's machine, even after versioning and testing?  "Too bad.  It should work, so I can't help."  I'd be out of business, Remus.

Comment: @marc: yes, silly dbas... I'm just trying to pland a seed here, get ppl to think at the db more as a resource under version control rather than the 'lets open ssms and modify out table!'. I know in practice is impossible not to rely on if exists()  (or objec_id is not null, which I actually prefer, like gbn). I guess seal pups are doomed... arctic vile pest

Comment: @gbn: maybe so - but if you have dba's in a different company and half the time they're really not pro's, it's hard to maintain "strict control". IF EXISTS() checks mitigate possible problems.

Comment: @marc_s: the strict controls are on our side with source control, automatic synching, coldloads etc. So we can use ALTER. Over half of my DBAs are either Sybase or DB2 specialists, so I'm used this environment.

Comment: (Realizing this is zombiing a thread) I'm not sure you can answer the question, "What do you do in SQL Server to CREATE OR ALTER?" with, "Don't CREATE OR ALTER in SQL Server". ;^) Well, I mean, I guess you *did*, but I'm not sure you *should*... "*The first rule of CREATE OR ALTER Club is, 'Don\'t CREATE OR ALTER CREATE OR ALTER Club!!'*"

Answer (score 4):

I'd use `OBJECT_ID(...) IS NOT NULL` before a DROP.

Object identifiers have to be unique, so it works without using system tables:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.ExistingTable ON dbo.AnotherTable FOR UPDATE
AS 
SET NOCOUNT ON
GO
```

gives

```
Msg 2714, Level 16, State 2, Procedure MetaClass, Line 3
There is already an object named ExistingTable ' in the database.
```

I normally use ALTER because of how we work with source control, etc.

Comment: I finally get what you're saying here... and while OBJECT_ID is also proprietary, this is a much more compact way to perform the check.

Comment: I did not know OBJECT_ID is proprietary... it's probably in Sybase too though

Comment: How would you write the query? If object id is not null then what? Drop object? Is there such a statement in T-SQL?

Answer (score 3):

I always `alter` my objects because a `drop` is really bad practice and can leave your DB in an bad state if an object fails to create (24/7 db!), as well as what the other posters have mentioned about nuking permissions.

Editors like Sublime, Atom, and VS Code will let you make code snippets as templates for these to quickly gen-up your skeleton script. SQL 2016 now finally supports `DROP IF EXISTS` construct, but it still approaches from the wrong direction - that everything is a `drop/create` instead of a one time `create` in the distant past and `alter` from then on. Also, I have tried to make my headers as short as will possibly work, so I don't get any fancier than `create proc dbo.myproc as` as the `create` stub.

Views:

```
if objectproperty(object_id('dbo.myview'), 'IsView') is null begin
    exec('create view dbo.myview as select 1 c')
end
go
alter view dbo.myview as
    -- select *
    -- from table
go
```

Procs:

```
if objectproperty(object_id('dbo.myproc'), 'IsProcedure') is null begin
    exec('create proc dbo.myproc as')
end
go
alter procedure dbo.myproc as
    set nocount on
    -- Add the stored proc contents here...
go
```

UDF (scalar):

```
if objectproperty(object_id('dbo.myudf'), 'IsScalarFunction') is null begin
    exec('create function dbo.myudf returns int as begin return null end')
end
go
alter function dbo.myudf(@s varchar(100)) returns int as
begin
    -- return len(@s)
end
go
```

UDF (tabular):

```
if objectproperty(object_id('dbo.myudf'), 'IsTableFunction') is null begin
    exec('create function dbo.myudf returns @t table(x int) as begin return end')
end
go
alter function dbo.myudf(@s varchar(100))
    returns @result table (
        -- Columns returned by the function
        id int identity(1, 1) primary key not null
        ,result varchar(100) null
    )
begin
    return
end
go
```

Comment: Thanks, good point.  In cases where uptime is sensitive, I've taken to doing the DROP/CREATE inside of a transaction, which I think is effectively the same as ALTER.  But yes, ALTER is more surgical.

Answer (score 2):

That's basically the way to do it, yes. I just wonder if you have a particular reason to use the "EXEC" approach:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES WHERE ROUTINE_NAME = 'SynchronizeRemoteCatalog' AND ROUTINE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' AND ROUTINE_TYPE = 'PROCEDURE')
    EXEC ('DROP PROCEDURE dbo.SynchronizeRemoteCatalog')
```

Why not just:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES WHERE ROUTINE_NAME = 'SynchronizeRemoteCatalog' AND ROUTINE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' AND ROUTINE_TYPE = 'PROCEDURE')
    DROP PROCEDURE dbo.SynchronizeRemoteCatalog
```

???

For triggers, there's `sys.triggers`. Those are system catalog views in the "sys" schema - not strictly or directly tables, really.

Marc

Comment: I started using EXEC because sometimes when I sent the script to clients where the objects did *not* exist, SQL Server would complain.  Maybe it's superstition, but it hasn't hurt anything.

Answer (score 2):

> The year is 2017 and SQL Server has CREATE OR ALTER

SQL Server 2016 SP1 and SQL Server vNext have new T-SQL language statement – **CREATE [OR ALTER]** for:

- STOREDPROCEDURES
- FUNCTIONS
- TRIGGERS
- VIEWS

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverstorageengine/2016/11/17/create-or-alter-another-great-language-enhancement-in-sql-server-2016-sp1/

Comment: For the lucky guys that have SQL 2016 SP1 and above, this is now the way to go :)

Answer (score 2):

I prefer `CREATE-ALTER` approach (not syntax) over `DROP-CREATE` for two reasons:

- permissions (with `DROP-CREATE` you have to recreate them)
- object_id (altering object won't change it)

**Example `DROP-CREATE`:**

```
--Initial creation:
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.my_proc
AS
SELECT *
FROM dbo.a
WHERE i < 10;
GO

SELECT OBJECT_ID('dbo.my_proc');
GO


-- Recreating
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS dbo.my_proc;
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.my_proc
AS
-- some meaningless comment
SELECT *
FROM dbo.a
WHERE i < 10;
GO

SELECT OBJECT_ID('dbo.my_proc');
GO
```

**[DB Fiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=e5318629b1017c5cd50efe8b368b6454)**

As we can see the `object_id` has changed.

**Example 2: `CREATE-ALTER`**

```
-- Initial creation
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.my_proc2
AS
SELECT *
FROM dbo.a
WHERE i < 10;
GO

SELECT OBJECT_ID('dbo.my_proc2');
GO

-- Altering
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.my_proc2
AS
-- some meaningless comment
SELECT *
FROM dbo.a
WHERE i < 10;
GO

SELECT OBJECT_ID('dbo.my_proc2');
GO
```

**[DB Fiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=d639ba67eecdc115f85467f18c71b0d5)**

In this scenario the `object_id` remains the same.

---

Sample scenario when this can cause some problems. Let's assume that we use SQL Server 2016 Query Store and force to use specific query plan for stored procedure.

## DROP-CREATE

```
USE T1;
GO
-- make sure that Query Store is READ_WRITE 
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[a]') AND type in (N'U'))
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[a](
    [i] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [g] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [z] VARCHAR(10)
);
END
GO

-- populate table (15k records)
INSERT INTO dbo.a(g, z)
SELECT NEWID(), number
FROM (SELECT CAST([key] AS INT) AS number 
    FROM OPENJSON( '[1' + REPLICATE(',1',3000-1)+']')
    ) AS num
GO 5

-- initial creation
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.my_proc
AS
SELECT *
FROM dbo.a
WHERE z LIKE '12%'
AND 1 = (SELECT 1);
GO

-- Clustered Index Scan
EXEC dbo.my_proc;

EXEC sp_query_store_flush_db; 

SELECT qsq.query_id,
    qsq.query_text_id,
    qsq.context_settings_id,
    qsq.[object_id],
    OBJECT_NAME(qsq.[object_id]) AS [object_name],
    qsp.is_forced_plan,
    qsqt.query_sql_text,
    qsrs.count_executions,
    CAST(qsp.query_plan AS XML) AS sql_query_plan
FROM sys.query_store_query qsq
JOIN sys.query_store_query_text qsqt
ON qsq.query_text_id = qsqt.query_text_id
JOIN sys.query_store_plan qsp
ON qsq.query_id= qsp.query_id
JOIN sys.query_store_runtime_stats qsrs
ON qsrs.plan_id = qsp.plan_id
WHERE query_sql_text LIKE '%dbo.a%'
AND qsq.[object_id] <> 0
ORDER BY qsq.query_id;
GO
--dc1

-- creating index
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_dbo_a_z
ON dbo.a([z] ASC) INCLUDE ([i], [g]);
GO

-- index seek
EXEC dbo.my_proc;

EXEC sp_query_store_flush_db; 

SELECT qsq.query_id,
    qsq.query_text_id,
    qsq.context_settings_id,
    qsq.[object_id],
    OBJECT_NAME(qsq.[object_id]) AS [object_name],
    qsp.is_forced_plan,
    qsqt.query_sql_text,
    qsrs.count_executions,
    CAST(qsp.query_plan AS XML) AS sql_query_plan
FROM sys.query_store_query qsq
JOIN sys.query_store_query_text qsqt
ON qsq.query_text_id = qsqt.query_text_id
JOIN sys.query_store_plan qsp
ON qsq.query_id= qsp.query_id
JOIN sys.query_store_runtime_stats qsrs
ON qsrs.plan_id = qsp.plan_id
WHERE query_sql_text LIKE '%dbo.a%'
AND qsq.[object_id] <> 0
ORDER BY qsq.query_id;

-- forcing plan GUI, clustered scan
-- dc3

EXEC sp_query_store_flush_db; 
SELECT qsq.query_id,
    qsq.query_text_id,
    qsq.context_settings_id,
    qsq.[object_id],
    OBJECT_NAME(qsq.[object_id]) AS [object_name],
    qsp.is_forced_plan,
    qsqt.query_sql_text,
    qsrs.count_executions,
    CAST(qsp.query_plan AS XML) AS sql_query_plan
FROM sys.query_store_query qsq
JOIN sys.query_store_query_text qsqt
ON qsq.query_text_id = qsqt.query_text_id
JOIN sys.query_store_plan qsp
ON qsq.query_id= qsp.query_id
JOIN sys.query_store_runtime_stats qsrs
ON qsrs.plan_id = qsp.plan_id
WHERE query_sql_text LIKE '%dbo.a%'
AND qsq.[object_id] <> 0
ORDER BY qsq.query_id;
-- dc4

-- Clustered Index Scan
EXEC dbo.my_proc;

EXEC sp_query_store_flush_db; 
SELECT qsq.query_id,
    qsq.query_text_id,
    qsq.context_settings_id,
    qsq.[object_id],
    OBJECT_NAME(qsq.[object_id]) AS [object_name],
    qsp.is_forced_plan,
    qsqt.query_sql_text,
    qsrs.count_executions,
    CAST(qsp.query_plan AS XML) AS sql_query_plan
FROM sys.query_store_query qsq
JOIN sys.query_store_query_text qsqt
ON qsq.query_text_id = qsqt.query_text_id
JOIN sys.query_store_plan qsp
ON qsq.query_id= qsp.query_id
JOIN sys.query_store_runtime_stats qsrs
ON qsrs.plan_id = qsp.plan_id
WHERE query_sql_text LIKE '%dbo.a%'
AND qsq.[object_id] <> 0
ORDER BY qsq.query_id;
-- dc5

/* MAIN PART  - DROP - RECREATE */
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS dbo.my_proc;
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.my_proc
AS
-- some meaningless comment added by developer
SELECT *
FROM dbo.a
WHERE z LIKE '12%'
AND 1 = (SELECT 1);
GO

/* MAIN PART END */

-- Index Seek
EXEC dbo.my_proc;

EXEC sp_query_store_flush_db; 
SELECT qsq.query_id,
    qsq.query_text_id,
    qsq.context_settings_id,
    qsq.[object_id],
    OBJECT_NAME(qsq.[object_id]) AS [object_name],
    qsp.is_forced_plan,
    qsqt.query_sql_text,
    qsrs.count_executions,
    CAST(qsp.query_plan AS XML) AS sql_query_plan
FROM sys.query_store_query qsq
JOIN sys.query_store_query_text qsqt
ON qsq.query_text_id = qsqt.query_text_id
JOIN sys.query_store_plan qsp
ON qsq.query_id= qsp.query_id
JOIN sys.query_store_runtime_stats qsrs
ON qsrs.plan_id = qsp.plan_id
WHERE query_sql_text LIKE '%dbo.a%'
AND qsq.[object_id] <> 0
ORDER BY qsq.query_id;
-- object_id in query store is NULL
-- is_forced_plan flag is ignored !!!
```

First execution:
[image: DC1]

Adding index and execute:
[image]

Forcing plan:
[image]
[image]

Another execution:
[image]

After `DROP-CREATE`:
[image]

---

## CREATE - ALTER

```
USE T2;
GO
-- make sure that Query Store is READ_WRITE 
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[a]') AND type in (N'U'))
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[a](
    [i] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [g] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [z] VARCHAR(10)
);
END
GO

-- populate table (15k records)
INSERT INTO dbo.a(g, z)
SELECT NEWID(), number
FROM (SELECT CAST([key] AS INT) AS number 
    FROM OPENJSON( '[1' + REPLICATE(',1',3000-1)+']')
    ) AS num
GO 5

-- initial creation
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.my_proc
AS
SELECT *
FROM dbo.a
WHERE z LIKE '12%'
AND 1 = (SELECT 1);
GO

-- Clustered Index Scan
EXEC dbo.my_proc;

EXEC sp_query_store_flush_db; 
SELECT qsq.query_id,
    qsq.query_text_id,
    qsq.context_settings_id,
    qsq.[object_id],
    OBJECT_NAME(qsq.[object_id]) AS [object_name],
    qsp.is_forced_plan,
    qsqt.query_sql_text,
    qsrs.count_executions,
    CAST(qsp.query_plan AS XML) AS sql_query_plan
FROM sys.query_store_query qsq
JOIN sys.query_store_query_text qsqt
ON qsq.query_text_id = qsqt.query_text_id
JOIN sys.query_store_plan qsp
ON qsq.query_id= qsp.query_id
JOIN sys.query_store_runtime_stats qsrs
ON qsrs.plan_id = qsp.plan_id
WHERE query_sql_text LIKE '%dbo.a%'
AND qsq.[object_id] <> 0
ORDER BY qsq.query_id;
-- ca1
GO

-- creating index
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_dbo_a_z
ON dbo.a([z] ASC) INCLUDE ([i], [g]);
GO

-- index seek
EXEC dbo.my_proc;

EXEC sp_query_store_flush_db; 
SELECT qsq.query_id,
    qsq.query_text_id,
    qsq.context_settings_id,
    qsq.[object_id],
    OBJECT_NAME(qsq.[object_id]) AS [object_name],
    qsp.is_forced_plan,
    qsqt.query_sql_text,
    qsrs.count_executions,
    CAST(qsp.query_plan AS XML) AS sql_query_plan
FROM sys.query_store_query qsq
JOIN sys.query_store_query_text qsqt
ON qsq.query_text_id = qsqt.query_text_id
JOIN sys.query_store_plan qsp
ON qsq.query_id= qsp.query_id
JOIN sys.query_store_runtime_stats qsrs
ON qsrs.plan_id = qsp.plan_id
WHERE query_sql_text LIKE '%dbo.a%'
AND qsq.[object_id] <> 0
ORDER BY qsq.query_id;
--ca2

-- forcing plan GUI
--ca3

EXEC sp_query_store_flush_db; 
SELECT qsq.query_id,
    qsq.query_text_id,
    qsq.context_settings_id,
    qsq.[object_id],
    OBJECT_NAME(qsq.[object_id]) AS [object_name],
    qsp.is_forced_plan,
    qsqt.query_sql_text,
    qsrs.count_executions,
    CAST(qsp.query_plan AS XML) AS sql_query_plan
FROM sys.query_store_query qsq
JOIN sys.query_store_query_text qsqt
ON qsq.query_text_id = qsqt.query_text_id
JOIN sys.query_store_plan qsp
ON qsq.query_id= qsp.query_id
JOIN sys.query_store_runtime_stats qsrs
ON qsrs.plan_id = qsp.plan_id
WHERE query_sql_text LIKE '%dbo.a%'
AND qsq.[object_id] <> 0
ORDER BY qsq.query_id;
--ca4

-- Clustered Index Scan
EXEC dbo.my_proc;

EXEC sp_query_store_flush_db; 
SELECT qsq.query_id,
    qsq.query_text_id,
    qsq.context_settings_id,
    qsq.[object_id],
    OBJECT_NAME(qsq.[object_id]) AS [object_name],
    qsp.is_forced_plan,
    qsqt.query_sql_text,
    qsrs.count_executions,
    CAST(qsp.query_plan AS XML) AS sql_query_plan
FROM sys.query_store_query qsq
JOIN sys.query_store_query_text qsqt
ON qsq.query_text_id = qsqt.query_text_id
JOIN sys.query_store_plan qsp
ON qsq.query_id= qsp.query_id
JOIN sys.query_store_runtime_stats qsrs
ON qsrs.plan_id = qsp.plan_id
WHERE query_sql_text LIKE '%dbo.a%'
AND qsq.[object_id] <> 0
ORDER BY qsq.query_id;
--ca5
GO

/* MAIN PART  - CREATE-ALTER */
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.my_proc
AS
-- some meaningless comment added by developer
SELECT *
FROM dbo.a
WHERE z LIKE '12%'
AND 1 = (SELECT 1);
GO

/* MAIN PART END */

-- Clustered Index Scan
EXEC dbo.my_proc;

EXEC sp_query_store_flush_db; 
SELECT qsq.query_id,
    qsq.query_text_id,
    qsq.context_settings_id,
    qsq.[object_id],
    OBJECT_NAME(qsq.[object_id]) AS [object_name],
    qsp.is_forced_plan,
    qsqt.query_sql_text,
    qsrs.count_executions,
    CAST(qsp.query_plan AS XbML) AS sql_query_plan
FROM sys.query_store_query qsq
JOIN sys.query_store_query_text qsqt
ON qsq.query_text_id = qsqt.query_text_id
JOIN sys.query_store_plan qsp
ON qsq.query_id= qsp.query_id
JOIN sys.query_store_runtime_stats qsrs
ON qsrs.plan_id = qsp.plan_id
WHERE query_sql_text LIKE '%dbo.a%'
AND qsq.[object_id] <> 0
ORDER BY qsq.query_id;

-- is_forced_plan is valid
```

First execution:
[image]

Adding index and execute:
[image]

Forcing plan:
[image]
[image]

Another execution:
[image]

After `CREATE-ALTER`:
[image]

## Result

With Drop-Create we lost forced plan.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's a while off: [link text](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=127219)

typical script for me:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sysobjects WHERE name = 'ig_InsertDealer' AND type = 'P')
    DROP PROC dbo.ig_InsertDealer
GO 
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.ig_InsertDealer
...
GO
GRANT EXECUTE ON dbo.ig_InsertDealer TO ...
GO
```

Comment: I would recommend using a) the "sys" schema, and b) a more focused system view, e.g. sys.tables for tables, sys.triggers for triggers etc., instead of just the generic "sysobjects" (which will be deprecated soonish).

Answer (score 1):

I'll use either depending on context: my initial-build or major refactoring scripts will use check/drop/create, pure maintenance scripts use alter.

Answer (score 0):

I have a template, which allows to execute a script several times without errors.

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[aaa_test]') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
    EXEC('CREATE PROCEDURE aaa_test AS')
    EXEC('GRANT EXECUTE ON aaa_test TO someone')
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE aaa_test 
     @PAR1 INT,
     @PAR2 INT=0
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT @PAR1 AS Par1, CASE @PAR2 WHEN 0 THEN 'Default' ELSE 'Other' END AS Par2
END
GO
```

Execution:

```
EXEC aaa_test 1
EXEC aaa_test 1,5
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not drop an object. Dropping an object suffers from two problems:

1) If the CREATE fails, you no longer have an object.
(You can use transactions to avoid that, at the expense of a lot of boilerplate code)

2) You lose permissions on the object, if you do not explicitly re-create them.

---

I prefer to create a blank object within an "if not exists" condition, and then use ALTER, and have written helper procedures for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Just to my [extend previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45000500/5070879).

Another reason why I prefer `CREATE-ALTER` over  `DROP-CREATE` approach. It could lead to losing specifc properties about object. For example `ExecIsStartup`:

```
USE master
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.silly_logging(id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
                               ,created_date DATETIME DEFAULT GETDATE()
                               ,comment VARCHAR(100));
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.my_procedure 
AS
INSERT INTO dbo.silly_logging(comment)
VALUES ('SQL Server Startup');
GO

-- mark procedure to start at SQL Server instance startup
EXEC sp_procoption @ProcName = 'dbo.my_procedure'
    , @OptionName = 'startup'   
    , @OptionValue = 'on';


SELECT name, create_date, modify_date, is_auto_executed
FROM master.sys.procedures
WHERE is_auto_executed = 1;
--name  create_date modify_date is_auto_executed
--my_procedure  2017-07-28 06:36:21.743 2017-07-28 06:36:24.513 1
```

Now let's assume that someone wants to update this procedure using `DROP-CREATE`:

```
DROP PROCEDURE dbo.my_procedure;
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.my_procedure 
AS
-- adding meaningless comment
INSERT INTO dbo.silly_logging(comment)
VALUES ('SQL Server Startup');
GO

SELECT name, create_date, modify_date, is_auto_executed
FROM master.sys.procedures
WHERE is_auto_executed = 1;
-- empty
```

And if you are not aware of it or you don't check you will end up with procedure that won't start.