# Entity Framework 5 - Not populating foreign key

Tags: entity-framework-5

I'm very new to Entity Framework, so I apologize if this is a stupid question...

Here is my POCO:

```
[Table("RegistrationCodes")]
public class RegistrationCode
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Guid Code { get; set; }

    public int? UserId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public UserProfile User { get; set; }

    [StringLength(500)]
    public string Notes { get; set; }
}
```

When I retrieve the object from my DBSet with the code below, UserId is always null.

```
return this.Context.RegistrationCodes.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Code == code);
```

I've checked the database and verified that the UserId is not null. Additionally, i have profiled and can see that the UserId is being requested from the database.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is it UserId or UserProfile thats null?

Comment: UserId and UserProfile are both null is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ohhhhh my, don't I feel stupid...

Here's what was happening, I run the code and I can see the UserId field is updated in the database. Every time I restart the application, code migrations would run add do an AddOrUpdate to the table which would null out the UserId column.

Can we just delete this question all together?

Comment: Leave the question here and accept your own answer. It's a good example about the trap an always running `Seed` method can lead into. Others have encountered this problem too, like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13510341/entity-framework-5-migrations-setting-up-an-initial-migration-and-single-seed-o