# EF - code first - automatic update database

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I want to use automatic migrations in my code, but every time I change something in the model I need to run `update-Database` manually. Can I do it automatically?

This is the configuration:

```
public class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<ManualContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
        AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;
    }
    ...
}
```

And `AppActivator`:

```
[assembly: WebActivator.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(AppActivator), "PreStart")]
[assembly: PostApplicationStartMethod(typeof(AppActivator), "PostStart")]
[assembly: ApplicationShutdownMethod(typeof(AppActivator), "Stop")]

namespace Manual.Web
{
  public static class AppActivator
  {
    public static void PreStart()
    {
      Database.SetInitializer(
               new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<ManualContext,Configuration>());
      Database.SetInitializer(new ManualDbInitializer());

      MeasurementConfig.RegisterUnits();
      MiniProfilerPreStart();
    }
    ...
  }
```

And ManualDbInitializer - for seed (when creating DB at first time):

```
public class ManualDbInitializer : CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<ManualContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(ManualContext context)
    {
        ManualDbInitializerSeed.SeedForDB(context);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> If you are deploying your application you may want it to automatically upgrade the database (by applying any pending migrations) when the application launches. You can do this by registering the MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion database initializer. A database initializer simply contains some logic that is used to make sure the database is setup correctly. This logic is run the first time the context is used within the application process (AppDomain).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621#initializer

Comment: But I do have MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion  in my code... Did you read it? What did I do wrong?

Comment: @TamarG: What is `ManualDbInitializer()`? you set it after `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<ManualContext,Configuration>()`.

Comment: it's for the seed.. I edited my question with the code

Comment: @TamarG: In fact your `ManualDbInitializer` is `CreateDatabaseIfNotExists` so you are setting the `Database` initializer to `CreateDatabaseIfNotExists` instead `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion`. move your `Seed()` method to your `Configuration` class.

Comment: If I'll move Seed() to Configuration - it'll be called only when a new DB is  created or every time the DB get updated?

Comment: @TamarG:I dont check it myself but in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13510341/entity-framework-5-migrations-setting-up-an-initial-migration-and-single-seed-o/14157184#14157184, Jon Smith says :'Microsoft comment says "This method will be called after migrating to the latest version." However my testing shows that it is called every time the software starts"'.

Comment: Thanks. I removed "Database.SetInitializer(new ManualDbInitializer());" and I checked in my seed() if my context if empty and only then I filled it. Thanks a lot!