# Why does my EF6 automatic migration not working?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I'm implementing automatic migration in my ASP.NET MVC project. Migration is working when I manually run `add-migration` or `update-database`.

However, automatic migration is not working when I'm running the project and set the configuration to `AutomaticMigrationsEnabled=true`.

Here is the setup I have; I expect that whenever I change something in model, it should reflect on my database every time I start up the project.

Configuration.cs

[image]

AutoMigrationEntities.cs

[image]

Thank you. Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Enabling automatic migration will only avoid step of add-migration it will not automatically update database with changes.

Automatic migration will avoid using Add-Migration (unless we really need to) and focuses on letting Code First Migrations automatically calculate and apply the changes. we will need to Update-Database to get Code First Migrations to push the changes to our model to the database.

Run the

> Update-Database

command in Package Manager Console will update database which will reflect database changes.

If you want both things automatically then please refer [EF - code first - automatic update database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26212490/ef-code-first-automatic-update-database)

You can make the MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion initializer to use the connection string that was used by the context that triggered the migration in the first place. This is done by passing useSuppliedContext: true to the MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion constructor as below.

```
Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<AutoMigrationEntities,Configuration>(useSuppliedContext: true));
```

Comment: Hi @Rutuja, Thank you for your response. Yes, I understood. But the `Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<AutoMigrationEntities, Configuration>());` should do the job of migrating the pending changes on my model. I added a breakpoint and It is being hit upon startup. I'm not sure what I missed in my config.

Comment: You can make the MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion initializer to use the connection string that was used by the context that triggered the migration in the first place. This is done by passing useSuppliedContext: true to the MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion constructor.

Comment: I did not apply the `useSuppliedContext: true`. It seems the migration is working automatically by accessing any of the DB set on my `AutoMigrationEntities` like this one `var genders = await db.Genders.ToListAsync();` Thanks.