# It is possible to generate SQL script to create only stored procedures for EF mapping?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I have a SQL Server database project with definition of tables, relations, keys, indexes, security, publish profiles, etc. and I also have an ASP.NET Core MVC project.

The issue is that I would like to use Entity Framework for DML operations but the catch is that I am allowed to use only stored procedures (probably from the security perspective, where application account will have only execution permission on those stored procedures and read only on specific tables).

I found that EF can map `.SaveChanges()` method to stored procedures via model builder like this example

```
modelBuilder.Entity<SubjectArea>().MapToStoredProcedures();
```

From the MS docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/fluent/cud-stored-procedures

It can also generate them with `migration` command. I am not experienced with migrations, but I would like to only generate the SQL for the stored procedures creation and add this script (which was not run yet) into the SQL Server database project (the workaround is to run migration into separate database and generate scripts from the database into the database project, but it seems not nice).

Is it possible to do it somehow?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Code First Migrations and Stored Procedures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14139445/code-first-migrations-and-stored-procedures)

Comment: @Steve Greene, I don't understand, how is this duplicate ? The OP of your link want to move existing stored procedures into EF migration scripts, but i want to generate the SQL script for the purpose of the `.SaveChanges()` from the EF entities into the database, but not run them, only generate.