# How to add stored procedures to existing database model (in Code first Approach)?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first

I am working on a project where code first E-F was implemented but not able to access the stored procedures.How could I add them to the model now?

Comment: Why do you need stored procedures when using code first entity framework? You would normally use the controllers to incorporate the logic that a stored procedure would.

Comment: I am working on an existing project.I want to use the stored procedures.It will be much time consuming in re building existing logic.Cant we access the store procedures now?

Answer (score 1):

Well, if it's an existing database, you could just use Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio to access the stored procedures. They can be found under 'Your database' > 'Programmability' > 'Stored Procedures' in the Object Explorer. Though I'm pretty sure that using both stored procedures AND entity framework is not common practice.

To answer your question, right-click the Stored Procedures filter in the Object Explorer mentioned above and click the Stored Procedure option to add a stored procedure to your database.

If you don't want to use MSSMS, you can also add stored procedures in C# using the migration functionality that entity framework provides, explained in [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20715292/5064575)

Comment: Actually Stored procedures were already  there in my db.When implementing the Code first ef, might forgot to add Stored Procedures in "OnModelCreating" method along with the db tables.Now I want to add the SPs to the existing Entity model.Is that was possible?

Comment: You might be able to bind a model to your stored procedures using `modelBuilder.Entity<YourModel>().MapToStoredProcedures();`, which is explained on [this MSDN page.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn468673(v=vs.113).aspx)

Comment: Yes I have Added this to the OnModelCreating mrthod, and Built the solution.But no luck. Do I need to run the migrations?Once again?

Comment: The OnModelCreating method is called when you first use your data model, or when you use an initialize method in your startup code: `Database.SetInitializer(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<MyDbContext>());`