Generating idempotent SQL migration script in Entity Framework Core when it contains stored procedures throws error when running on database
I have a few stored procedures that I'd like to be created during a migration step in Entity Framework Core.
I added a new migration, and in the Up() method I put this simple script:
var sp = @"CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyStoredProcedureFromMigration]
    AS
    BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON;
        SELECT * FROM Students WHERE FirstName LIKE '%dummy%'
    END";

migrationBuilder.Sql(sp);

In my Azure Devops pipeline, I generate the idempotent migration script with a DotNetCoreCli task:
  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: 'Create EntityFramework migration script'
    inputs:
      command: custom
      custom: ef
      arguments: 'migrations script --idempotent --project $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/src/[MigrationsProject].csproj --startup-project $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/src/[MigrationsProject].csproj --output $(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/script.sql'
      workingDirectory: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)

But Entity Framework Core then generates this script:
IF NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM [__EFMigrationsHistory]
    WHERE [MigrationId] = N'20240827132758_NameOfMigration'
)
BEGIN
    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyStoredProcedureFromMigration]
       AS
       BEGIN
          SET NOCOUNT ON;
          SELECT * FROM Students WHERE FirstName LIKE '%dummy%'
       END
END;
GO

which returns an error when running from a SqlAzureDacpacDeployment task in the pipeline:

Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'PROCEDURE'.

If I remove the --idempotent argument, the script is valid but then I get errors because some of the tables already exist, as the generated script is no longer idempotent.
How can I generate a valid new migration script that runs without errors when it contains the creation of stored procedures?

possible duplicate of Creating a stored procedure if it does not already exist

@GSerg, entity framework is generating the script for me, so I have little control over the outcome.

But you have control over what you put in that var sp. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20715292/create-stored-procedures-using-entity-framework-code-first#comment132502314_51998117?

I do have control over the query string, but any GO statement that is in there will be placed inside its own IF NOT EXISTS check by Entity Framework. I cannot remove that GO statement in the sample from your link, as the CREATE PROC needs to be the only statement in the batch.

I was not linking to a sample, I was linking to a comment.

Thanks @GSerg. I've seen that used before; not my favourite setup but I'm gonna look into it now.

Use CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE.

@GertArnold using that results in a different error: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'OR'

Old SQL Server version? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-procedure-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#or-alter

@GertArnold - the issue is that create procedure needs to be the first statement in the batch, not that the or alter variant of it isn't supported.

I posted a question on efcore github as well (https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/34555)

@BenThul, you're right.

You cannot nest CREATE PROCEDURE or CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE inside an IF block, it has to be a standalone batch, e.g. db<>fiddle

You can do something like: EXEC('CREATE OR ALTER ...') but there should probably be a better way

Hi Reinder, check this thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/78954128/7687666
