# How can I write this stored procedure with EF in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures

How can I write this stored procedure with EF in C#?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE FilterDocumentByNumber
    @Number NVARCHAR(30)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM Document
    WHERE DocumentNumber = @Number
      AND CostGroupId IN (SELECT CostGroupId
                          FROM CostGroups
                          WHERE CostGroupType = 1)
END
```

Thanks

Comment: You might find it helpful to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and include a bit more information in your question, so that we know what you've tried and can help you out more.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you create sql views / stored procedure using Entity Framework 4.1 Code first approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7667630/can-you-create-sql-views-stored-procedure-using-entity-framework-4-1-code-firs)

Comment: If you are unfamiliar with Entity Framework, I suggest you start with something a little more simple - for example fetching a list of records from the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SO is not a website when you throw everything here and expected people finish the job for you.

Anyway, to give you some hint, I give you a straight suggestion:

`Select CostGroupId     From    CostGroups    Where      CostGroupType   = 1` 
--> Stored these in A collection, like an array:

```
var costGroupsIdArr = ctx.CostGroup.Where(x=>x.CostGroupType == 1).Select(x.CostGroupId).toArray();
```

Then from here, get your main query:

```
Select  *
From    Document
Where   DocumentNumber  =   @Number
```

Here is the last result:

```
var result = ctx.Document.Where(x=>x.DocumentNumber == number && vostGroupsIdArr.Contains(x.CostGroupId)).ToList();
```

You can try to figured out yourself what else needed from my snippet