# update-database not working in Code first

Tags: entity-framework, stored-procedures, code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I am using entity  framework and Codefirst to create a Stored procedure. 
As I reed, we should do some steps in package manager to create SP.

1 - enable migration

2- add-migration MYclass

3- update-database

and in `Myclass(new created)` I write my SP code in UP() method to create SP. works fine!! BUT when I change SP and run update-database again it does not work and I need to do another add-migration command to create new MYclass2. Is that right? I mean every time I should write add-migration?

this is mycode

```
  public override void Up()
        {
            Sql(@"Create procedure testSp 
                        as 
select std.Id as stdName, std.Name as MajorName, mj.Name from dbo.Students as std
inner join dbo.Majors as mj on std.Id = mj.Id
");
        }

        public override void Down()
        {
            Sql("drop procedure testSp");
        }
```

when I run update-database again the result is `"No pending explicit migration"`

even if I change the SQL query to "Alter procedure...." it does not work , no change happens.
thanks

***EDITED***

consider this scenario, I want to change my SP name(just an example)
so I need to change the query to "Alter store procedure tespSP2 ..." 
or any other change, should I run add-migration again?? or update-database is supposed to do it??

Comment: Various techniques discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7667630/can-you-create-sql-views-stored-procedure-using-entity-framework-4-1-code-firs).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in entity framework migrations added to a _migrationHistory table, you can delete the last row of this table [it's not recommended]

or you can use rollback/undo command

`Update-Database -TargetMigration:MigrationsName`

then use `update-database -force`

Comment: So what will happen after this code? consider I want to change my storePr query, what should I do step by step?

Comment: you can add another migration and change your code there, it's the best way
or if you are not in production you can do it manually, first remove the last row of the _migrationHistory table and then run the update-database command , it will be re update your database with the last migration

Comment: but when we use Code first it is supposed to not access to SQl server and its tables. I thought update database should do it automatically!!! So ther is not any REwirte on migration, am i right?? every time we should create new migration.

Comment: yes you right,
I suggest it get around entity-framework rules
you need to add a new migration every time you change a query