# How can I check if a stored procedure exists in PERVASIVE database before creating it?

Tags: stored-procedures, exists, pervasive-sql

I want to create a stored procedure in a Pervasive database, but only if it does not yet exist.

I found something for SQL Server:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
               FROM sys.objects 
               WHERE type = 'P' AND OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID('dbo.MyProc'))
   exec('CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyProc] AS BEGIN SET NOCOUNT ON; END')
GO
```

I found that code on this link [How to check if a stored procedure exists before creating it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2072086/how-to-check-if-a-stored-procedure-exists-before-creating-it).

So I want something really similar for Pervasive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to execute the `IF NOT EXISTS` syntax outside of a Stored Procedure in Pervasive.  You could create a procedure taking a procedure name and drop it if it exist.  Something like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DropProcIfExists(in :procname char(20))
AS
BEGIN
 IF( EXISTS (SELECT xp$Name FROM X$proc WHERE Xp$Name = :procname) ) THEN
  Exec('DROP Procedure "' + :procname + '"') ;
 END IF;
End#

call DropProcIfExists ('myProc')#
```

So your SQL would be something like:

```
call DropProcIfExists('MyNewProc')#
Create Procedure MyNewProc()
AS
BEGIN...
```

Comment: No.  Easiest way would be to create Procedures that drop the trigger / function if it finds them.  You'd need to change the SELECT query to look for the function and trigger.