# In Pervasive stored procedure how can I drop a table and recreate it using a variable

Tags: stored-procedures, pervasive

This works if I use an actual table name rather than the variable name (:TName) in the two statements.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Make_Snap(in :TName VARCHAR(20));

BEGIN

   DROP TABLE IF EXISTS :TName;
   select * into :TName from Inventory_mstr;
END;
```

but I get the error: Syntax error: DROP TABLE IF EXISTS<< ??? >>?

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I check if a stored procedure exists in PERVASIVE database before creating it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37122700/how-can-i-check-if-a-stored-procedure-exists-in-pervasive-database-before-creati)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is that your syntax is incorrect.  Pervasive does not support the `if exists` in that manner.
You'll use something like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DropProcIfExists(in :procname char(20))
AS
BEGIN
 IF( EXISTS (SELECT xp$Name FROM X$proc WHERE Xp$Name = :procname) ) THEN
  Exec('DROP Procedure "' + :procname + '"') ;
 END IF;
End
```

[Previously asked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37122700/how-can-i-check-if-a-stored-procedure-exists-in-pervasive-database-before-creati)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I finally got to work:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Make_Snap(in :TName VARCHAR(20));

BEGIN
    DECLARE :INDB  varchar(10); 

    set :INDB = (SELECT count(Xf$Name) FROM X$File WHERE Xf$Name = :TName);
        IF :INDB > '0'  
        THEN  
            Exec('DROP Table "' + :TName + '"') ;
            Exec('select * into "' +:TName + '" from Inventory_Mstr'); 
        ELSE
            Exec('select * into "' +:TName + '" from Inventory_Mstr'); 
        END IF;
 End
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another example that is supposed to work, though I have not tested it anywhere yet:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Make_Snap(in :TName VARCHAR(20));
BEGIN
    Exec('DROP Table IF EXISTS "' + :TName + '"') ; 
    Exec('select * into "' +:TName + '" from Inventory_Mstr'); 
End
```