# Different ways to check if a stored procedure exists in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I found two ways to check if a stored procedure exists in our current code:

```
if object_id('dbo.procedure_to_drop') is not null
```

vs

```
if exists (select * from sysobjects where id = object_id('dbo.procedure_to_drop') and sysstat & 0xf = 4)
```

What's the difference between them and which one is the prefer way?

Comment: Easier to read and understand by others would be my preferred method. The first one would be my choice. Other options are `SELECT * FROM   sysobjects WHERE  id = object_id(N'[dbo].[MyProc]') and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsProcedure') = 1` or `SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE type = 'P' AND OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID('dbo.MyProc')` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2072086/how-to-check-if-a-stored-procedure-exists-before-creating-it

Comment: Here's a 3rd way: SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES WHERE ROUTINE_TYPE = 'PROCEDURE'; Some cols are ROUTINE_NAME, ROUTINE_DEFINITION (proc sql code), ROUTINE_SCHEMA, CREATED, LAST_ALTERED. I'd use this or @Morzel's answer - some way you can use the procedure name instead of the object_id - it's easier to read.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first version checks if any object exists with the given name. In that case, if you make a typo and enter a name of a table, it will still pass.
About the second version is obsoleted because there is no guarantee if future versions will support to use sysstat. (Check the msdn site: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-compatibility-views/sys-sysobjects-transact-sql)

I wouldn't use any of them. I would prefer to check objects directly by name:

```
if exists (select 1 from sys.procedures where name = 'procedure_to_drop')
```

sys.procedures: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-procedures-transact-sql

If you have sql server 2016, you can use the new language elements to do the same depending on what you want:

- CREATE OR ALTER: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-procedure-transact-sql
- DROP IF EXISTS: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/drop-procedure-transact-sql