# How can i implement a 'IF NOT Exists Create Procedure with Parameter'?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ddl

I'm trying to do the following

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE name = 'test' AND type = 'P')
BEGIN
    CREATE PROCEDURE test (@val1 INT)
END
```

Just getting an error of incorrect syntax.

Comment: tag your dbms name

Comment: SQL Server 2012

Comment: You want to read this question and the *second* answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2072086/how-to-check-if-a-stored-procedure-exists-before-creating-it

Answer (score 2):

Found a solution that worked for me as i wanted to. That is, create a procedure with a parameter if it doesn't exist.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.test') IS NULL
BEGIN
EXEC('CREATE PROCEDURE test(@val1 INT) AS SELECT  * FROM sys.objects')
END
```

Thank you guys for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

There seems no error with - `IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT  * FROM sys.objects WHERE name = 'test' AND type = 'P')`

Try using

```
BEGIN 
 CREATE PROCEDURE test(@val1 INT) AS
  SELECT  * FROM sys.objects
  END
```

Use PROCEDURE instead of PROC , Define your query in procedure as required and you are all set. :)

Comment: Still get the same error. Don;t think using PROCEDURE in full makes any difference. The problem seems with creating the procedure in between begin and end for the if statement,