# Is "SET NOCOUNT ON" a good choice for a placeholder stored procedure body?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

These answers ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27970943/12484), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2885664/12484)), using code from [this article](https://dattatreysindol.com/2012/05/29/tips-n-tricks-t-sql-an-elegant-way-to-create-or-alter-stored-procedures-in-one-go-for-easy-maintenance/), recommend using the statement `SET NOCOUNT ON` as a temporary placeholder/dummy body for a stored procedure whose body will be overwritten shortly.

Neither those answers nor that article specify *why* `SET NOCOUNT ON` was chosen as the value for the temporary stored procedure body.

My question: Why is `SET NOCOUNT ON` a good choice for a temporary stored procedure body which will (if all goes well) be overwritten in a subsequent operation?  Is there a better alternative?

Some criteria that come to mind for what might constitute a good temporary / placeholder stored procedure body:

- Fails in an obvious way at runtime if for some reason the subsequent `ALTER` of the stored procedure doesn't happen as planned;
- Is easy to understand by future developers maintaining the stored procedure;
- Doesn't add any significant overhead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To better meet the "criteria" from my question, I've landed on replacing `SET NOCOUNT ON` with a [`RAISERROR`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/raiserror-transact-sql) statement.

My code to ensure a stored procedure exists before running an `ALTER PROCEDURE` on it ends up looking like:

```
-- Create the sproc with a temporary body if it doesn't exist yet. 
-- We'll set the real body in the ALTER PROCEDURE statement below.
IF NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT * FROM sys.objects
    WHERE name = 'MyStoredProcedureNameHere'
    AND type = 'P'
) BEGIN
  EXEC ('CREATE PROCEDURE MyStoredProcedureNameHere AS
    RAISERROR (''The ALTER PROCEDURE to set the body for MyStoredProcedureNameHere did not run as it should have!'', 16, 1);');
END
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE MyStoredProcedureNameHere AS ...
```

So, if the ALTER PROCEDURE somehow fails to run, then if my stored procedure gets executed, it'll raise an error instead of silently doing nothing (as would be the case with a body consisting only of `SET NOCOUNT ON`).

Credit for this approach: http://www.codeofhonor.com/blog/a-better-way-to-update-sql-stored-procedures

Comment: It is common to raise a "Not Implemented" error when you make sproc shells and want to be sure no one thinks that they are finished.

Comment: Yep, that's the approach I attempted to take here!

Answer (score 5):

This is probably because including `SET NOCOUNT ON;` is [considered good practice](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1226/set-nocount-on-improves-sql-server-stored-procedure-performance/).  It is included in the template SP, generated by SSMS.  From the MSDN article on [NOCOUNT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189837.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

> NOCOUNT ON prevents the sending of DONE_IN_PROC messages to the client for
>   each statement in a stored procedure. For stored procedures that
>   contain several statements that do not return much actual data, or for
>   procedures that contain Transact-SQL loops, setting SET NOCOUNT to ON
>   can provide a significant performance boost, because network traffic
>   is greatly reduced.

The idea is `NOCOUNT` is first used a placeholder.  Later you add to, rather than replace, this statement.